# bed entries collapse based on score column

Tags: bed, bedtools

I have a bed file where some entries have the exact same chr:start-end but change in the name and score column. I would like to apply bedtools or a similar tool to obtain a filtered file where for each set of chr:start-end entries, only the one with the highest score (column 5) is used, the others filtered out. I would like to do this with a bed format toolkit (bedtools, etc) rather than scripting it.

Comment: I searched for bedtools merge or bedtools collapse, but couldn't find a way.

Answer (score 2):

Use [BEDOPS](https://github.com/bedops/bedops) `bedmap --max-element` or `bedmap --max-element-rand` to grab the maximal-scoring element over mapped intervals, e.g.:

```
$ sort-bed elements.unsorted.bed5 > elements.bed5
$ bedops --merge elements.bed5 > merged.bed3
$ bedmap --max-element merged.bed3 elements.bed5 > answer.bed
```

The file `answer.bed` will contain the maximal-scored element from `elements.bed5` that overlaps the merged intervals in `merged.bed3`.

The `--max-element` and `--max-element-rand` options differ on handling ties. The first option grabs the first match from ties by `sort-bed` (lexiographical) sort order; the second option grabs a random match on ties.

The option you pick would depend on what you're doing with the answer. Picking a random hit might be better if you're doing downstream statistical tests, for instance.

You can add `--sci` and `--prec <int>` options to format the score output to your desired level of precision. I think the default assumption is six digits of precision; adjust as needed.

There are also `--min-element` and `--min-element-rand` options for, conversely, reporting minimal-scoring elements.

For more information: http://bedops.readthedocs.io/en/latest/content/reference/statistics/bedmap.html#score-operations

Answer (score 1):

[groupby](http://bedtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/content/tools/groupby.html) from bedtools might help you:

```
bedtools groupby -i variantsToRepeats.bed -grp 1-3 -c 5 -o max
```

`-grp` to select the columns to group by
`-c` to select the columns to summarize
`-o` to select how to summarize the column selected.

Comment: Could you please expand your answer? An explanation might help future readers. Thanks! I edited your question from the help page you linked. I hope it is now better, and I understood it correctly

Comment: How lazy can people be? I even linked the help page and to anybody with an IQ over 80 the options should be immediately obvious.

Comment: Without the explanation your answer becomes pretty unhelpful if the location of the help files changes